# How to pass dynamically created RelativeLayout to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created the class which extends `Fragment` which creates the `RelativeLayout`.I want to know how to pass that dynamically created `RelativeLayout` to the another fragment containing `FrameLayout` and set that `RelativeLayout` to that `FrameLayout`.

Comment: what you can do is make a variable of the data type you required in the fragment and a setter function in it set that variable this is how we can do this, if you want to pass int, float or boolean you can use bundle and the setArguments method.

Answer (score 1):

Why creating the layout outside the fragment? that's why fragments have onCreaveView & onViewCreated methods in their lifecycle.

I would suggest you to pass a STATE variable (int,string) to the fragment using Bundle, 
and on the onCreateView method get the state in build the view according to it.

You can find simple example how to pass bundle and use it inside the fragment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063378/how-pass-bundle-from-fragment-to-fragment)

If you find yourself must pass a view to fragment you can use 3rd class which will hold it. But that's really not the right way...

Comment: but I more than one dynamic layouts from which I want to select any one of them...

Comment: is it possible to pass layout through bundle..??

Comment: only parcable objects

Answer (score -1):

I haven't try it yet but it might work

```
class CustomFragment extends Fragment{

    RelativeLayout relativeView;

    CustomFragment(RelativeLayout view){
        relativeView = view;
    }

    onCreateView(){
       //inflate layout and get FrameLayout
       frameLayout.addView(relativeView);
    }
}
```

and your `RelativeLayout`

```
RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(context);
// custom it as you wish
CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment(r);
```

Comment: fragments wont allow constructor having variables in it, we can only use default constructor.