# Communication between one fragment to another

Tags: java, android

I am new to fragments. I added two edit texts in first fragment and I want to send that edittext data to second fragment.

I am using a bundle, but its printing null in second fragment.

Can anyone tell me how to send data to other fragment?

First fragment

```
    nextt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _view) {
            int viewId = _view.getId();
            FragmentTransaction ft;
            switch (viewId) {
                case R.id.Button1:
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    SecondFrag secondFrag = new SecondFrag();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("deviceInst",viewId);
                    secondFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                    ft.replace(R.id.total_frame_content, secondFrag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

In second fragment

```
      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_new, container, false);
    String value = getArguments().getString("deviceInst");
    System.out.println("TTTT"+ value);
```

Comment: you have to read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: you passing Int & getting in String check your code

Comment: @Ashwini Bhat..if i want to pass both string and int in that case?

Comment: putString() & getString(), putInt() & getInt() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063378/how-to-pass-bundle-from-fragment-to-fragment check this @pruthvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first fragment you pass an `int` as an argument.

`bundle.putInt("deviceInst",viewId);`

And then, in your second fragment you try to get that argument by using 
`getArguments().getString("deviceInst")`

which will fail, so to get the argument you pass you need to use `getArguments().getInt("deviceInst")`

For encapsulating the needed data, a good tip is to have a static `newInstance()` method in your fragments that requires data.

Here's a post about it.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/bCD7Zvd945d

Comment: and for passing string?

Comment: `bundle.putString("deviceInst",viewId);`

Comment: If i put viewid in passing string its showing error

Comment: What's the error? If you want to put a string in the bundle, make sure the `viewId` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change like

```
 int value = getArguments().getInt("deviceInst");
```

instead of

```
 String value = getArguments().getString("deviceInst");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the following changes in your code.

```
bundle.putString("deviceInst",editText.getText().toString());
```

Then in your second fragment you can get that argument by using

```
getArguments().getString("deviceInst")
```

> Here **editText** is the instance of the edit text in the first fragment.

Comment: Bro how to pass listview data?

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener() and then onItemClick retrieve the data from your array list / data source you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
As you have passed int in the bundle, you need to use getInt() in your receiver fragment.
For example:
 SecondFrag secondFrag = new SecondFrag();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("deviceInst",viewId);
                    secondFrag.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.total_frame_content, secondFrag).commit();

In receiver fragment
  String value = getArguments().getInt("deviceInst");
```